# Custom filter to discriminate when two files are equals

Tags: git

In my repository I have some json files I want to add to git. These json are made by: some fields, which change each day with i.e. the latest timestamp, and a 'content' field which is the true content of the json.

I want to tell git that if the json is updated in the content field, it must be seen as 'modified', otherwise even if other fields changes, it must be seen as 'up to date'.

I read about gitattributes and I created a filter program textconv which outputs only the content field to be compared. It works well for "diff" command, however "git status" still sees it as 'modified'.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git status` will see a file as modified if it changes at all, even if those changes are irrelevant to you.  That's because this algorithm is cheap and easy to compute from file system metadata, whereas the algorithm you propose would require reading in the entire file every time, which is very expensive if the files are large or there are many files.

You *can* use a smudge/clean filter (see the `gitattributes(5)` manual page) that will strip everything but the `content` field out of the JSON on clean and add those extra fields back on smudge.  However, if you do this, `git status` will still see the files as modified if they change at all, even in a way that makes them clean to the same thing.  You'd need to do a `git add` to make the file no longer appear to be modified.